# How to run two methods as thread one after another using ExecuterService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I am trying to  execute two method where two methods will execute one by one after some interval, and I am using `ExecuterService`. I have implemented some portion of the code but the full functionality I could not achieve till now, here I am posting my code

```
public class ExampleExecuterService {

private static final int MYTHREADS = 3000;
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(MYTHREADS);

    Object methodList[]={

            aMethod(),bMethod()
    };


    for(int i=0;i<methodList.length;i++){
        Object myList = methodList[i];
        Runnable worker = new MyRunnable(myList);
        executor.execute(worker);
    }
    executor.shutdown();
    // Wait until all threads are finish
            while (!executor.isTerminated()) {

            }
  System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");

}

public static class MyRunnable implements Runnable {

    private Object myList=null;

    MyRunnable(Object myList) {
        this.myList = myList;
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {


        try{

            myList.wait(2000);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

private static Object bMethod() {
    System.out.println("This is inside method a ");
    return null;
}
private static Object aMethod() {

    System.out.println("This is inside method b ");
    return null;
}

}
```

I want `aMethod()` and `bMethod()` that should run 20 seconds after and in the end the `executer` will stop. How to do that with my code. Somebody please help me.

Comment: Is there a problem with grouping aMethod() and bMethod() together in cMethod() which has a 20s sleep in between?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> Object methodList[]={
>    aMethod(),bMethod()
> };
> ```

This is not a list of your methods. This is a list of what your methods return (=null).

In Java, methods are **not** objects. If you want to store methods in a list or array, you have to wrap them inside objects. The usual way of doing this is by using the `Runnable` interface or something of the kind.

In your case, it could look like this:

```
Runnable[] methods = new Runnable[]{
   new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for method a
       @Override
       public void run(){  // method a
          System.out.println("This is inside method a");
       }
   },
   new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for waiting
       @Override
       public void run(){   // method to wait for 20s
          try{ Thread.sleep(20000); }catch(Exception e){}
       }
   },
   new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for method b
       @Override
       public void run(){  // method b
          System.out.println("This is inside method b");
       }
   }
};
```

After that you can submit this array of "methods" to your executor service:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
for(Runnable r : methods)
   service.submit(r);
service.shutdown();
```

However, keep in mind that `ExecutorService` is primarily meant to execute tasks concurrently (= in parallel), while you want to execute them sequentially.

In you know that you'll always need a sequential, single-thread behaviour, you should drop `ExecutorService` and simply:

```
for(Runnable r : methods) 
   r.run();
```

EDIT: Full main method

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    Runnable[] methods = new Runnable[]{
       new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for method a
           @Override
           public void run(){  // method a
              System.out.println("This is inside method a");
           }
       },
       new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for waiting
           @Override
           public void run(){   // method to wait for 20s
              try{ Thread.sleep(20000); }catch(Exception e){}
           }
       },
       new Runnable(){  // Object wrapper for method b
           @Override
           public void run(){  // method b
              System.out.println("This is inside method b");
           }
       }
    };

    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    for(Runnable r : methods)
       service.submit(r);
    service.shutdown();

    // Wait until all threads are finish
    while (!service.isTerminated()) {}
    System.out.println("\nFinished all threads");
}
```

Comment: but here how i will run method a and b

Comment: but where i should write your code ??can you edit my question ?Then it will be very helpful

Comment: OK I added the full main method in my post

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find a better solution for the waiting 20 seconds in between, but how about this:

```
    ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    service.submit(task1);
    service.submit(() -> {
        Thread.sleep(20000);
        return null;
    });
    service.submit(task2);
```